# Why does our implementation of the Facebook Like button only post a URL on a user's Facebook profile?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

We thought we added the proper tags to enable Facebook to display our Likes in plain english, such as:

Bob likes **Why We Sold TechCrunch To AOL, And Where We Go From Here** on **TechCrunch**

However, Facebook is only posting:

Bob likes **http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/28...**

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks for your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Uhh.. are you forgetting to write the link text?

[Why We Sold TechCrunch To AOL, And Where We Go From Here on TechCrunch](http://www.w3schools.com/)